# HTML Link Not Active Within Div

Tags: html, css, href

I'm unable to figure out why an HTML link is not active within two DIV blocks in my code. It works fine if I test it outside the DIV's in the main body. HTML is as follows:

```
<div class = "window">
    <div id = "body">
      <h3>What To Do...</h3>
      <p>
        Newport is an incredible city, with lots of things to do. For a huge list of ideas, check out <a href='http://www.discovernewport.org'>Discover Newport</a>
      </p>
      <p>We are partial to the following...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#body {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#body a:link,
#body a:hover,
#body a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.window {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  padding-top:0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin:8em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 64, .9);
  color: #000040;
  border-radius:10px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: you set all links to text-decoration: none; what do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "active"? Do the links not work? As Brunis pointed out `text-decoration:none;` removes the underline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z-index: -1;` is the culprit; bcz of this `link` are deactivated and not working. check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dojoxele/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```
#body a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none; <!-- ??? -->
}
```

Does taking this line out solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'not active'?

If you wish the link to be styled differently then you need add an 'active' pseudo class in your CSS.

Like so:

```
#body a:active {}
```